# Lift Controller

Tags: digital-logic, logic-gates

I am making a lift controller circuit in my university. Below are the details of the project. 
I just want some guidance from you guys how to make it work. How do i set the direction of the motor ( if it is called to a specific floor) and how to make it go to another floor ( when that floor button is pressed)

THANKS IN ADVANCE FOR ANY TYPE OF HELP ~!!!!

[image]

Comment: You can come here after you have done some study and work and ask specific questions about what you have done. For school projects, you need to show some effort before asking for help. Voting to close the question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a school project with no effort shown.

Comment: Well i just want to get a little bit of start. !!!! I will do the rest, if you guys could help a little, that would be great thanks

Comment: You may get some help in comments and perhaps even an answer, but I have other things to do.

Comment: This place is not a forum, and not a good place for discussion. It's a question and answer site for electronic design. So you should ask a specific question that can be answered (not just discussed). Also you need to provide as much background/context as possible, because leaving it to us to guess or ask for more details means most people won't bother, and the question will be closed.

Comment: you have not thought this through .... if you did, then you would not be assuming that we know which controller you are using

Comment: start by turning a motor on for one or two seconds .... once you have that figured out, start the motor when a button is pressed and run for a second or two ..... when you have that figured out, start the motor when a button is pressed and stop motor when a sensor is activated ...... keep expanding your code until you have a finished product

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're given a set of requirements and a brief narrative.  From this, you should develop a set of conditional statements, like "if-then-else" in programming.  Each statement represents a logic equation, with the conditional variables you inputs and the result of the statement your output.

After you write your statements, convert each one to a logic equation.

e.g.:  **If a is true AND b is NOT true**
           **then C=1**

The above would become **C = a * ~b**     (where ~ = NOT)

One last bit of encouragement, if you plan to follow this path as a profession, get used to vague requests and minimal but ambiguous input from the S&M department.  Learn to write your own spec; its accuracy will improve outcome.